# image_view cannot be run in diamondback

Tags: image-view, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to run the image_view node, but it was not successful..it is the package and its binary but cannot be run. I was actually following "http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera" to invoke "rosrun image_view image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color". Unfortunately, the output I obtained is "[rospack] couldn't find package [image_view]
" . The node is already there in fact as I navigate, I could find in "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/image_pipeline/image_view/bin$"

Any ideas??

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9137/image_view-cannot-be-run-in-diamondback/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-20**:
Please see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support#Guidelines_for_mailing_list_messages. In particular be sure to copy and paste your commandline and the output you get (how do you know it was "not successful"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just successfully found the solution. I've run this command: "source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash" :-). To be precise run as recommended in the ROS wiki:
echo "source /opt/ros/cturtle/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-21**:
Yes joq, it's true.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-21**:
That will work until the next time you login or create a new terminal window. For a permanent fix, add it to the end of your `~/.bashrc`, as recommended in the install instructions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a ROS_PACKAGE_PATH issue. One possibility: when you ran rosinstall in following the openni installation instructions, did you point it to /opt/ros/diamondback? (this is noted in the [install instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni) but it's subtle).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

## **Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-20**:
Another thing the error is reduced to one already after running "roswtf", the output is "Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context

Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

## ERROR PYTHONPATH [/opt/ros/unstable/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src:] is invalid: Multiple roslib directories in PYTHONPATH (there should only be one)

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
"

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-20**:
in ~/.bashrc, i have these for the last 3 related lines: source /opt/ros/cturtle/setup.sh
source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
source /home/shah/ni/setup.bash,  I commented the first line (cturtle), however, when I run roscd I still give me ":/opt/ros/unstable/ros$" as the output, that means it is still pointing to the unstable..any thoughts?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-02-20**:
You probably need to update your ~/.bashrc file if you've changed distributions from unstable->diamondback. It should have the line "source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash" -- and none that mention cturtle or unstable (it would appear you might currently have all three).

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-20**:
There are 3 errors outputted. It seems that my ROS system is using unstable one, though I prefer to use diamondback instead. I can run other nodes, but it is actually using unstable version, which I do not want. I run "roscd", it gave this path: /opt/ros/unstable/ros$

## **Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-20**:
After running roswtf, I got this output: Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context

Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

## ERROR PYTHONPATH [/opt/ros/unstable/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/roslib/src:] is invalid: Multiple roslib directories in PYTHONPATH (there should only be one)

Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
connection to [/image_view_1298227468589958529] timed out
connection to [/image_view_1298227184442580969] timed out
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:

- /image_view_1298227184442580969->/rosout (/rosout)
- /image_view_1298227477610316242->/rosout (/rosout)
- /rviz_1298227453247877962->/rosout (/rosout)
- /kinect_base_link->/rosout (/rosout)
- /kinect_base_link2->/rosout (/rosout)
- /kinect_base_link1->/rosout (/rosout)
- /openni_camera->/rosout (/rosout)
- /kinect_base_link3->/rosout (/rosout)

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:

- /image_view_1298227468589958529
- /image_view_1298227184442580969

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:

- service [/image_view_1298227184442580969/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/image_view_1298227184442580969/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://shah-laptop:33079]
- service [/image_view_1298227468589958529/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/image_view_1298227468589958529/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://shah-laptop:36106]
- service [/image_view_1298227184442580969/set_logger_level]

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-20**:
If diamondback was installed properly from debs then you shouldn't have to add image_view explicitly to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, so I suspect there's a larger issue here. Can you try running some other nodes? Can you do basic things like roscore, rostopic list, etc.? Have you tried roswtf?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-20**:
I run all the commands given in the installation instructions and try to run "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$PWD:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" in the image_view directory..but still, no change..Could you make it more explicit on how should I point/remedy it.